# knife ec2 create server & chef Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

After running knife ec2 create server I expected there to be a Node in chef, but there isn't.

What's the typical process for keeping chef and ec2 in sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ideally yes, the newly created node should report to your chef-server. If it doesnt then download the chef-client recipe and deploy it in your server, when you create a node using knife ec2 command, it should automcatically deploy the chef-client in your newly created node and it should report to your chef-server. This is actually very even I work on chef but never encountered this problem ever.

Comment: I'm not sure what was happening. The new nodes are now showing up in chef. The problem I'm having now is that I send a role via --run-list to create server and it runs that role, but when I look at the node on chef-server it doesn't have anything in it's run list.